# Refactoring code for custom date component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a date component (working GIF at the bottom).

There isn't a problem with the working of the code but rather the code I wrote seems messy and something hard for any other person to comprehend.

Note: Please look at the GIF below. Also, Ignore the styling

this is what I am doing. For the date Component in screen, I am creating refs and state like this

```
class OnBoarding extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.d1 = React.createRef()
        this.d2 = React.createRef()
        this.d3 = React.createRef()
        this.d4 = React.createRef()
        this.d5 = React.createRef()
        this.d6 = React.createRef()
        this.d7 = React.createRef()
        this.d8 = React.createRef()
    }
    state = {
        name: '',
        emailAddress: '',
        dob: '',
        male: null,
        female: null,
        keyboard: false,
        d1: null,
        d2: null,
        d3: null,
        d4: null,
        d5: null,
        d6: null,
        d7: null,
        d8: null
    }

dobHandler(number, flag) {
        const completeFlag = `d${flag}`
        this.setState({[completeFlag]: number})
        flag = flag + 1
        if (flag < 9 && number) {
            const nextFlag = `d${flag}`
            const textInputToFocus = this[nextFlag]
            textInputToFocus.current.focus()
        }
    }
```

And then rendering them like this

```
       <View style={styles.dob}>
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d1}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="D"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 1)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d2}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="D"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 2)}
                        />
                        <Text>/</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d3}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="M"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 3)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d4}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="M"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 4)}
                        />
                        <Text>/</Text>
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d5}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="Y"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 5)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d6}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="Y"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 6)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d7}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="Y"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 7)}
                        />
                        <TextInput
                            ref={this.d8}
                            numberOfLines={1}
                            maxLength={1}
                            style={styles.textInputDob}
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            placeholder="Y"
                            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, 8)}
                        />
                    </View>
```

The reason I have made so many ref is because the moment someone enters something in the current textInput, I want the focus to moved to the next one, which happens in dobHandler function.

Can someone help me in improving quality/optimizing and if this is the wrong way of doing it, then hint me on **How to achieve this alternativekly**

[image]

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - Use the Code Review Stack Exchange to get advice on improving your working code. Use Stack overflow to get your code working :)

Comment: You should not do it this way. The ref should be to the same component and then use events to change focus. See this article for an approach https://codedaily.io/tutorials/65/Create-a-Segmented-Auto-Moving-SMS-Code-Verification-Input-in-React

Answer (score 8):

Among many ways, you can write this as,

```
const placeholders = [ 'D', 'D', 'M', 'M', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'];

class OnBoarding extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.refs = Array(8).fill(0).map(_ => React.createRef())
  }

  state = {
    name: '',
    emailAddress: '',
    male: null,
    female: null,
    keyboard: false,
    dob: Array(8).fill(null)
  }

  dobHandler(number, index) {
    const { dob } = this.state
    dob[index] = number;
    this.setState({ dob:  [ ...dob ]})
    const ref = this.refs[index + 1]
    if (number && ref && ref.current)
      ref.current.focus()
  }

  render() {
    <View style={styles.dob}>
      {this.refs.map((ref, i) => (
        <>
          <TextInput
            ref={ref}
            numberOfLines={1}
            maxLength={1}
            style={styles.textInputDob}
            keyboardType="numeric"
            placeholder={placeholders[i]}
            onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, i)}
          />
         {(i == 1 || i == 3) && <Text>/</Text>}
       </>        
      ))}
    </View>
  }
}
```

Since you have a repetitive set, you can use arrays while conditionally inserting the slashes where needed based on index.

Comment: I've made some significant edits since I posted. It should be ready for use now

Comment: More fully answer and like for the repeat, it's more scaleable and flexible this way.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a `function` to return a `TextInput` with `ref`, `placeholder` and `num` as parameters

```
renderTextInput(ref, placeholder, num) {
  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={ref}
      numberOfLines={1}
      maxLength={1}
      style={styles.textInputDob}
      keyboardType="numeric"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChangeText={number => this.dobHandler(number, num)}
    />
  )
}
```

Then call it inside the render method

```
return (
  <View style={styles.dob}>
    {renderTextInput(this.d1, "D", 1))}
    {renderTextInput(this.d2, "D", 2))}
    ...
    ...
  </View>
);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I have upvoted your answer but I want to see if there could be more optimal solution for this question. There is now an active bounty as well for this question if no one would be able to answer it, i follow your approach and grant you that bounty. Again, thanks a lot for answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using [Material UI datepicker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker), and store your DOB as a [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instead?

If you are using Material v4.x, simply follow the [demo](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker). Otherwise, you need to first install [material-ui-pickers package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-pickers). Then,

```
import { DatePicker, KeyboardDatePicker } from "material-ui-pickers"; // if and only if using Material v3.x
```

You can then replace your previous implementation with this:

```
  <KeyboardDatePicker
    autoOk
    variant="inline"
    inputVariant="outlined"
    label="Your DOB"
    format="MM/dd/yyyy"
    placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" /* use placeholder to guide how your user should enter the date format, in this case, I simply followed your GIF demo */
    value="" /* use a default value or leave it empty */
    InputLabelProps= {{ /* customise style of your label */ }}
    InputProps= {{ /* customise style of how your input should look like */ }}
    InputAdornmentProps={{ position: "start" }}
    onChange={date => handleDateChange(date)}
  />
```

Your dobHandler will no longer be needed. You will simply update your DOB state value or save your DOB using handleDateChange().

```
handleDateChange(date){
  /* do something whenever a new date is entered */
}
```

This should address the followings without your existing dobHandler function, and the long TextField per integer.

> I want the focus to moved to the next one, which happens in dobHandler function
>
> Answer: *This will be handled by Material UI's datepicker, refer to [demo here](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker#inline-mode)*